# Getting permission denied error when trying to create file for writing in VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I keep getting permission denied when trying to open the second file here for writing. I know the first file opens fine as I can write it out to the screen and I have set write permissions for users. Is this so simple that I'm being blinded by it???

```
css_org = server.MapPath("style.css")
css_new = server.MapPath("new_style.css")           
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForReading = 1 
Const ForWriting = 2        
Set objFile1 = fso.OpenTextFile (css_org, ForReading)
Set objFile2 = fso.OpenTextFile (css_new, ForWriting, True)  ' 500 error on this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be ASP, so you need to grant write permission to the user running the code (usually the service account running IIS), not the user who is logged into your web application.

Comment: I don't understand that? It's on the web so the user could be anyone. The file running the code has permission 777.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. 777 are Unix/Linux permissions. Your code is ASP code, which does not run on Unix/Linux servers. Please update your question with more information about your environment, how the code is supposed to be run, and by whom.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. 777 is what I see when changing them using FileZilla. On the server they are just plain old Read, Write, etc.     Turns out that this wasn't a code issue. The ISP reset the server and it works again. Thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: You can't change permissions on IIS through an FTP programme the way you can on a UNIX server.  They'll always show as 777 but that means nothing.  You need to open a remote desktop session, find the file or folder, right click on it and select the security tab.  The service account will probably be called IUSR_something

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing to the file outside of code to see if the user context can write to it?  It's probably not an issue with your code.  You may get a more informative error message if you try to write to it, say, with Notepad.  Also, you could try using SysInternals' "Process Explorer" -- their "Find Handle" feature to test that file to see if there is some process locking it.

Comment: The script is on a web server. I created the files that I would want to write to through file manager, set permissions to 777, but I still get the same 500 error permission denied. Clueless in Wisconsin here.